# AngularJS - How to transclude through directive, which has no transclusion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

folks! I have used AngularJS for a while and decided to put up a component system using directives with transclusion. One day I encountered a problem I was unable to overcome. The problem has to do with my directive, most likely.

In order to understand what the problem is, I will briefly go through the basic idea, how "the system" is supposed to operate.

## Structure

I have a directory dedicated for components:

[image]

For each component, I have HTML markup and CSS file in the components directory as follows:

[image]

And, HTML and CSS of component "nav" are like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='example-nav'>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example-nav{
    background:linear-gradient(#BA5454, #B34444);
    border-bottom:2px solid #E86B6B;
    box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    height:48px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:64px;
    width:100%;
}
```

## Usage

Components use directive "example-component". Here's an example of how it is used:

```
<example-component name="nav"></example-component>
```

Name is the name of component in the components directory.

## Directive

Now, after explaining some background here's the implementation of the directive and some other services and controllers utilized by the service:

```
var app = angular.module("example", []);

app.factory("ComponentsStyles", function(){
    return {
        stylesheets: []
    };
});

app.controller("HeadController", ["$scope", "ComponentsStyles",
function($scope, componentsStyles){
    $scope.stylesheetsComponent = componentsStyles.stylesheets;
}]);

app.directive("exampleComponent", ["ComponentsStyles",
function(componentsStyles){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            name: "@"
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<ng-include src=\"'components/' + name + '.htm'\"></ng-include>",
        controller: function($scope){
            componentsStyles.stylesheets.push($scope.name);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Yes, I do acknowledge the problem with stylesheets array, but let us not stick to that, unless it is relevant to the question. :-)

## Problem

The problem is mainly with the transclusion. As you can see from the directive implementation, it utilizes ng-include to fetch HTML contents. Because components should have the possible to translude for subcomponents, transclusion is to go through ng-include, if I understand correctly. At least this is the error I received in my console in Chrome:

[image]

According to AngularJS documentation there are two ways to deal with this problem (see this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdiv) for more information):

> To resolve, either remove the offending ngTransclude or check that
>   transclude: true is included in the intended directive definition.

But none of the options can resolve my issue, these fixes simply won't do it! I can't add transclude: true to ng-include - or can I?

So, my question is: **how to transclude through directive, which has no transclusion?**